# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "json" does not contain '/'

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

When I try to send data to server by POST method, I got this error on the server side:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "json" does not contain '/'.`

First I thought that date format from jQuery UI DatePicker is wrong and I changed it to "`yy-mm-dd`", but unfortunately is still does not work. I am really confused, because I don't know where is `'/'` which makes me trouble. I would be very happy if anybody decides to help me - Thank you

This is error, $.ajax and mapping are also below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "json" does not contain '/'
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ConsumesRequestCondition$ConsumeMediaTypeExpression.matchMediaType(ConsumesRequestCondition.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.AbstractMediaTypeExpression.match(AbstractMediaTypeExpression.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.ConsumesRequestCondition.getMatchingCondition(ConsumesRequestCondition.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfo.getMatchingCondition(RequestMappingInfo.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getMatchingMapping(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:64)
// snip
```

That is how I send data:

```
$.ajax({
       url: _getContextPath() + "/event/addEvent",
       method: "POST",
       contentType: "json",
       data: {
             "ownerId": $("#ownerIdHidden").val(),
             "title": $("#title").val(),
             "place": $("#place").val(),
             "startdate": $("#startDate").val(),
             "starthour": $("#startHour").val(),
             "duration": $("#duration").val(),
             "description": $("#eventDescription").val(),
             "invited": _getLoginsFromTable(invitedTable)
      }
  });
```

And here is how I try to map it in Spring MVC Cotroller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="event/addEvent", method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes="application/json")
public String addEvent(@RequestParam("ownerid") Long ownerid, @RequestParam("title") String title,
        @RequestParam("place") String place, @RequestParam("startdate") Date startDate,
        @RequestParam("starthour") Integer startHour, @RequestParam("duration") Integer duration, 
        @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam("invited") String[] invitedLogins){
    Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try{
(....)
```

**UPDATE**: now this is the code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: _getContextPath() + "/event/addEvent",
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
   data: {
        "ownerId": 3,
        "title": 3,
        "place": $("#place").val(),
        "startdate": (new Date($("#startDate").val())).getTime(),
        "starthour": $("#startHour").val(),
        "duration": $("#duration").val(),
        "description": $("#eventDescription").val()
  }
});
```

And mapping:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="event/addEvent", method=RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes="application/json")
public String addEvent(@RequestParam("ownerid") Long ownerid, @RequestParam("title") String title,
        @RequestParam("place") String place, @RequestParam("startdate") Long startDateMilis,
        @RequestParam("starthour") Integer startHour, @RequestParam("duration") Integer duration, 
        @RequestParam("description") String description){
    Session session = NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try{
```

And now I got: `POST http://localhost:8084/pracainz/event/addEvent 400 (Bad Request)`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: `MediaType.parseMediaType` tries to parse the *"json"* String literal into a `MediaType` but throws an exception because it's not a valid media type name. [The media type of JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) is `application/json`. Since all valid internet media types contain two parts separated by '`/`' all input without this character is guaranteed to be invalid.

This:

```js
$.ajax({
       url: _getContextPath() + "/event/addEvent",
       method: "POST",
       contentType: "json",
       // ...
```

should be:

```js
$.ajax({
       url: _getContextPath() + "/event/addEvent",
       method: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       // ...
```

Comment: thank you for help, I updated my post with your changes, but now I got: POST http://localhost:8084/pracainz/event/addEvent 400 (Bad Request), still something is wrong.

Comment: That's another question, isn't it?